# How do I make an animation run on click with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, cursor

I want to make a cursor that when you click, will change to one frame, then 0.5 seconds later, to the next, then back to how it before you clicked. The reason I need it to be css is that I am working on a css only project. I have tried using transition-delay, but you can't have multiple delays on the same property. I can make a cursor change to one frame when clicked, but no more. Here is the code for that:

```
body {
    cursor: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BlETOnm98yPP5xCHbkFiFREFHNTQqucd_kFkfkYNKKnNohHvvnM7NTlLFq3rAukha0q-JEkouEgvfZnHkrhrzGIaps33RSJOuDV-_NiaPwSfn_cYbp5ayvFkYo4idwDkm-yb1G_jEwpY1zbrNtunux_oGFV-ADsdBVkK5qFqxj5OXMt3Qyw5GDkLgf5cdBHCK91go-7TkV8gT3zwbSWT8gi5tgFkY3UhyTM_X8E0FOU7uLOYBYDlTrEiIuIgqPEWOaj5MbH0j1j871KiLY65x4UsadJDzkpjT3mbfXgoMfDu4p3bE_I9a3Ck2MZq76RxKTH4iDHNwyz2hA0E0BXh2tsoq3mBQEH0h5ywIEDpNqMMQQ1HD33jfqX6TxZT48R6dGso6s4yGruWrMhn4CEwbvuNhOQYEO_r9e8WsIurKqU9bZ7Uiy3YdEtzgKG-sXHV5wJZQv8G0sr-utR9Cu8EzoYBHNdC2Yh-2eE8MAM0yS_15zKp-7igRo9RNhA_0TUkDgb8c4DQ4nC91VfylAA-elZKZtxDySI9U1ZCou1F8q42HJdD8A62CODQ2tlLJ3GMILtXQMM-T_JLhKzzg7gaTk8o9-E3pC5WVyh-yN9dSS-7sUqDBtUUF4bPWgg1WN2CbcJKXzDre_fBkw8hQ5Hzy_2Gp2LoMeSFB1c=s25-no), auto;
}
body:active {
    cursor: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pg5NgqvH-ljQhDjHXV3EHSdX9jYo3_DP2S5r72qH53KZgHjLXBWZb5exYINk7zGA0Xl05TJ4vRdj6Yx1M4gNwLy4jDCjZ_ihsnmO_qDIh5GSxdemoWioqsNjBuR2dyhHy72bToMwv4XRm8a9Rul2hkh9WgpcFRgA8UDPV_D_wCOvxVw6QN6bR472ZQdjCy0QKvHmuzCbuTFnrMCScHJf8OiqJcjhlk04yvaeigm_TJgM8AAgcqtiMJ1MYH5ebI9O34-8HxSPrME47y_9jEN_RSgTPbKD77izoxx531jwIkYbJ5_bSD6NMFDsrub1hlmzexjblGs9bkoC8rbINmCHuUo-zHZaRW3cWkpx-tI4-XjVIgEeoDcwaL0IDOZop2t9aUfbmZQxng-kYVlNzSRwfkWwjAqwJJsS_68T7e7-W_mF1qbdL2BVbihpf8Vy7-8uXYlvHZbiqeiFfEsofThcGWopj8QwXN7Wqo4I8qX0bC7zJrao3UAFVwQ9ox80sWqeIXwJL4NoJs71x_v2GBPdFF74tyMptSL23oLv0c3PNREa2wkqxL1TFpg2VhwTFJRf=s25-no), auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you exactly tried to achieve but this may help with what you try to do:

I basically used a keyframe to animate the other cursor and made the animation 2s so that it will turn back again to the state before.

```
body {
    cursor: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BlETOnm98yPP5xCHbkFiFREFHNTQqucd_kFkfkYNKKnNohHvvnM7NTlLFq3rAukha0q-JEkouEgvfZnHkrhrzGIaps33RSJOuDV-_NiaPwSfn_cYbp5ayvFkYo4idwDkm-yb1G_jEwpY1zbrNtunux_oGFV-ADsdBVkK5qFqxj5OXMt3Qyw5GDkLgf5cdBHCK91go-7TkV8gT3zwbSWT8gi5tgFkY3UhyTM_X8E0FOU7uLOYBYDlTrEiIuIgqPEWOaj5MbH0j1j871KiLY65x4UsadJDzkpjT3mbfXgoMfDu4p3bE_I9a3Ck2MZq76RxKTH4iDHNwyz2hA0E0BXh2tsoq3mBQEH0h5ywIEDpNqMMQQ1HD33jfqX6TxZT48R6dGso6s4yGruWrMhn4CEwbvuNhOQYEO_r9e8WsIurKqU9bZ7Uiy3YdEtzgKG-sXHV5wJZQv8G0sr-utR9Cu8EzoYBHNdC2Yh-2eE8MAM0yS_15zKp-7igRo9RNhA_0TUkDgb8c4DQ4nC91VfylAA-elZKZtxDySI9U1ZCou1F8q42HJdD8A62CODQ2tlLJ3GMILtXQMM-T_JLhKzzg7gaTk8o9-E3pC5WVyh-yN9dSS-7sUqDBtUUF4bPWgg1WN2CbcJKXzDre_fBkw8hQ5Hzy_2Gp2LoMeSFB1c=s25-no), auto;
}
body:active {
    animation: cursor 2s;
}

@keyframes cursor{
  from{ 
    }
  to{
    cursor: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pg5NgqvH-ljQhDjHXV3EHSdX9jYo3_DP2S5r72qH53KZgHjLXBWZb5exYINk7zGA0Xl05TJ4vRdj6Yx1M4gNwLy4jDCjZ_ihsnmO_qDIh5GSxdemoWioqsNjBuR2dyhHy72bToMwv4XRm8a9Rul2hkh9WgpcFRgA8UDPV_D_wCOvxVw6QN6bR472ZQdjCy0QKvHmuzCbuTFnrMCScHJf8OiqJcjhlk04yvaeigm_TJgM8AAgcqtiMJ1MYH5ebI9O34-8HxSPrME47y_9jEN_RSgTPbKD77izoxx531jwIkYbJ5_bSD6NMFDsrub1hlmzexjblGs9bkoC8rbINmCHuUo-zHZaRW3cWkpx-tI4-XjVIgEeoDcwaL0IDOZop2t9aUfbmZQxng-kYVlNzSRwfkWwjAqwJJsS_68T7e7-W_mF1qbdL2BVbihpf8Vy7-8uXYlvHZbiqeiFfEsofThcGWopj8QwXN7Wqo4I8qX0bC7zJrao3UAFVwQ9ox80sWqeIXwJL4NoJs71x_v2GBPdFF74tyMptSL23oLv0c3PNREa2wkqxL1TFpg2VhwTFJRf=s25-no), auto;
  }
}
```

Maybe playing around with this will help you find your way to what you want to make.